# Javascript - Getting the name of the variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

When i call a function in javascript with a variable, for example:

```
CheckFunction(MyVariable);
CheckFucntion(MyVariable2);
```

And i have a function which, for example, checks if it's a number or not:

```
function CheckFunction(SOURCE){
//THE CODE ITSELF
};
```

I wanna log with the name of the original variable, how could i get that? I can get the name "SOURCE" with the code below:

```
Object.keys({SOURCE})[0])
```

But i'd like to log with the original name(*MyVariable*) from the called function.

Sample output in the console:

> **Area** is a number.

Where **Area** is a integer variable, and its name got checked from CheckFunction() function.

Comment: You can't do it.

Comment: You can't do that. The expression at the point of the function call is fully evaluated, and only the value is passed to the function.

Comment: Not possible (without code analysis), and almost surely a dupe.

Comment: Pass in an object instead: (`{ type: 'area', value: 23 }` for example), and use that as the basis for your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Javascript without any third-party tools to analyze the code.
Variables will not hold where they have been / come from.

The best you can do is what you already have with `Object.keys({SOURCE})[0])`
This is because you are converting the variable to a key and then reading the key again.

You would need a method on the variable to get the name as a string.

---

A better solution would be to send another parameter to the function with its location. ie . `CheckFunction(myVariable, 'onLoad);`. Alternatively, you could send an object with more verbose information that will help you track what you need.